# Angular help using code in multiple components

Tags: angular

I have a question i have this menu i want in component header.
and i have different div's in the main component that i want to hide/show on the right menu button. but when i split my code this doesn't work it only works when i have both in the same component.

```
<ul>
<li><a (click)="ShowHome()" class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a (click)="ShowAboutme()" href="#news">About me</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
```

the menu i want in my header.

```
 <div>
  <div class="box" *ngIf="showHome">
      <p>home 1</p>
      <p>home 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

the div i want to show when i press home.

```
<div>
  <div class="box" *ngIf="showAboutme">
    <p>about me 1</p>
    <p>about me 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another div for a different button.

```
showHome:boolean;
showAboutme:boolean;
ShowHome(){
this.showAboutme = false;
this.showHome = true;
}
ShowAboutme(){
this.showHome = false;
this.showAboutme = true;
}
```

and this is the code where i don't know where to put it if i want to split my code in 2 different components. when i put this in header.component.ts it works if i add all the html code in that component.

Any help would be very welcome :)

Comment: You should use the router to navigate between pages of your app. Read the documentation. https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: I just read it well kind of can't make heads of tails of it O.o way too many text to read which 99% will be irrelevant. could you give me an example if possible?

Comment: There are plenty of examples in the doc. If 8 minutes is the maximum you can take to learn what you're doing, you'll never get anywhere.

Comment: it's not i only have 8 minutes it's just that the official site isn't so clear to me. Way too many information i don't really need to make it happen so kind of makes me confused about what i do need and what not.

Comment: So invest more time in digesting the doc. Buy a book. Experiment. Learning takes time.

Answer (score 0):

When you are splitting your code into different components, you should use observable to support communication between two different component.

Any change to value in one component can be made available to another component via observable. here is the way to accomplish the same.

Create a shared service. let call it component service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
private titleSubject = new Subject<any>();
private loaderSubjectt = new Subject<any>();

constructor() { }



setTitle(title: string) {
    this.titleSubject.next({ title: title });
}

getTitle(): Observable<any> {
    return this.titleSubject.asObservable();
}

show() {
    this.loaderSubjectt.next({ state: true });
}

hide() {
    this.loaderSubjectt.next({ state: false });
}

}
```

Now import this shared service in your component
and injecting it to your constructor like this

```
constructor(private component: componentService) {}
```

Set the value like this

```
component.show()
component.hide()
```

Listen to change in those variable like this

```
this.appService.show().subscribe(res => {
                this.reportTitle = res.state;
            });
```

to read some text you can do

```
this.appService.getTitle().subscribe(res => {
                this.title = res.title;
            });
```